# Nginx root directory with nested symlinks

Tags: nginx, symlink

Our website (laravel) project directory is like this:

```
/home/user/project/{app,route,public_html,storage,...}
```

New releases are placed in:

```
/home/user/releases/v1
```

For some reason we have to link ***public_html*** directory for every release, so:

```
/home/user/releases/v1/public_html > /home/user/project/public_html
```

Nginx root diretory is:

```
/home/user/www/site/public_html
```

Which:

```
/home/user/www/site > /home/user/releases/v1
```

Since NGINX will follow symlinks, final root directory would be:

```
/home/user/project/public_html
```

Is there a way to fix this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `root` of your virtual host is `/home/user/www/site/public_html` and since `/home/user/www/site/public_html` is a symlink to `/home/user/project/public_html` and since `/home/user/project/public_html` is a symlink to your latest release - nginX `location` blocks will actually search inside `/home/user/releases/v1/public_html`.

---

Here is an example. Let's say we have a folder `/my_releases`. Everytime I publish/deploy a new release I will create a new subfolder inside `/my_releases` with the version of the release (`/my_releases/v1`, then `/my_releases/v2` and so on). All assets of the release will be inside the corresponding subfolder - so I will have

```
/my_releases
  |
  +---- /v1
  |      |
  |      +--- /css
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- /home.a120cd8.css
  |      |
  |      +--- /img
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- /logo.7f40c3a.svg
  |      |
  |      +--- /js
  |      |     |
  |      |     +--- /main.ba4de98.js
  |      |
  |      +--- /api
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- /index.php
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- /routes
  |      |              |
  |      |              +--- /login.php
  |      +--- /index.html
  |
  +---- /v2
  |      |
  |      +--- /css
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- /home.7845c7.css
  |      |
  |      +--- /img
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- /logo.23038ad.svg
  |      |
  |      +--- /js
  |      |     |
  |      |     +--- /main.acb33f1.js
  |      |
  |      +--- /api
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- /index.php
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- /routes
  |      |              |
  |      |              +--- /login.php
  |      +--- /index.html

........ next releases until the end of the world
```

My nginX is configured in such a way, that my virtual host has

```
server {
  server_name my.personal.web.site;
  root /var/www/public_html;
  .....
}
```

Before starting nginX, I have run the following 2 commands:

```
ln -s -f -n /my_releases/current /my_releases/v1
ln -s -f -n /var/www/public_html /my_releases/current
```

Then I started nginX - `service nginx start`. It will now serve `v1` of my web site/application.

Now, any time I deploy a new release, I run the following command (replace `v2` with the relevant revision)

```
ln -s -f -n /my_releases/current /my_releases/v2
```

### Don't forget to set the proper filesystem permissions and ownership.

Comment: But it's not like that and nginx still search inside "/home/user/project/public_html" path, i know this because any changes in release is ignored and changes in project main path is affcted. Also we have set "realpath_root" in fastcgi_param.

Comment: It's not completely clear from your question how it is. If it does not match my understanding - can you clarify?

Comment: If you run `realpath /home/user/www/site/public_html` command, the output will be  "/home/user/project/public_html", like that nginx search in there too.

Comment: Are you sure that `/home/user/project/public_html` is a symlink and it points to `/home/user/releases/v1/public_html` ?

Comment: In our situation "/home/user/releases/v1/public_html" points to "/home/user/project/public_html" not the other way around.

Comment: Well, then this is the answer that you're looking for - it should be the other way around.

Comment: If i understand correctly then we have to put "public_html" in every releases directory and we don't want that. We want "public_html" to be in the main project directory and only link it to every release.

Comment: It works exactly the opposite. You have a bunch of releases and every release has its own `public_html` which sits inside the release folder (v1, v2, v3, ....) Every time you publish/deploy a new release, you have to update the `root` of nginX. However, this requires sending the HUP signal to nginX to instruct it to reload the new `nginx.conf`. This is inconvenient - that's why you have a fixed `root` that is a symlink to your desired release. And when you deploy a new release - you simply update the symlink to point to the new release, and voila, everything instantly works.

Comment: Is it possible for you to demonstrate step by step tutorial so we can test it, Cause i think we say same thing but do it different ways.

Comment: Ok i got it, thanks for you help.